# Are there pharmacies on-board Tallink Silja cruise ships?

Tags: health, cruising, tallink-silja

As someone who always carries multiple drugs everyday, like epipens, desloratadin, vitamins etc. I want to always be able to get a new supply in case I misplace my drugs or if I'm forced to use any of them (the epipen effect only lasts for 15 minutes) so I wonder if there's a pharmacy on the Tallink Silja boats? Or if there's a doctor there with access to epipens etc?

Comment: Ferries (and cruise ferries) train on getting passengers from board with helicopters, which my parents saw when they traveled Netherlands to UK, but with an airlift, not an onboard landing of the helicopter.

Answer (score 4):

[The companies website](https://www.tallinksilja.com/good-to-know#16662123) states:

> ## **STATE OF HEALTH, PREGNANCY AND PHYSICAL DISABILITY**
>
> Our ships have on-board nurses who can assist passengers in the event of acute illnesses and provide first aid in connection with accidents. Note! Not in Star/Superstar.

If you have specific medicine you require just in case you may want to inform the company in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Vessels carry emergency medicine, and have officers with applicable medical training, or even nurses.

[WHO publishes](https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/43814/9789240682313_eng.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) a recommended list of medicines to be carried on board. Adrenaline is on the list of medicines. For a passenger vessel in Europe, I would expect them to have at least the WHO recommended minimum, in addition to officers trained in emergency medicine.

If you have a medical emergency on board, contact staff in any way you can, and make them aware of your situation.

If you have some pre-condition they should be aware of, ask for the officer in charge of medical emergencies, and tell that person about your pre-conditions.

You can not expect an pharmacy on board.